# Adding Adsense Ad to Google Sites programmatically via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, adsense, google-sites

Is there any workaround to add AdSense Ad programatically to page in Google Sites?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google has shut down the API serivce for Adsense in Google Sites:

https://support.google.com/sites/answer/3156640?hl=en&ref_topic=1046094

Here is Google's Apps Script API Reference for Adsenese:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_adsense

It appears that you cannot add Adsense ads programmatically. It looks like an information gathering tool for reporting, etc.

Maybe they will change the features in the future.

Perhaps having page templates pre-populated with Ads?

Good Luck.